# When do I have to initialize variables in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand tensor flow and how  understand it one has to first create ops and variables add them to the graph and then in a session those operations will be performed.
Then why in this piece of code I don't have to use the method initialize_all_variables()?
I was trying to add `init = tf.initialize_all_variables()` and then `sess.run(init)` but it was wrong. Why is this working without the initialization??

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np
x = tf.placeholder('float', [2,3])
y = x*2
z = tf.Variable([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]], name = "z")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x_data = np.arange(1,7).reshape((2,3))
    z.assign(x_data)
    res = sess.run(y, feed_dict = {x:x_data})
    print(res.dtype, z.dtype, z.get_shape())`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to read an uninitialized value. In the case above you are not reading `z` hence you don't need to initialize it.

If you look at at `variables.py` you see that `initialize_all_variables is a group node connected to all initializers`

```
def initialize_variables(var_list, name="init"):
...

 return control_flow_ops.group(
        *[v.initializer for v in var_list], name=name)
```

Looking at `z.initializer`, you can see it's an `Assign` node. So evaluating `tf.initialize_all_variables` in TensorFlow is the same as doing `session.run` on `z.assign(...`